react-draft-wysiwyg toolbar options not opening
react-draft-wysiwyg toolbar options not opening:

emoji.
font size.
font family.
link.
upload image.
color pick.

next 14.0.4
react 18.2.0
Github issue
enter image description here
similar problem found, using react is said to remove remove StrictMode in react

I had the same problem and I moved to tiptap because I couldn‘t find any other solution.
Here is the Github Repo

Update your Next.js configuration file and set the property reactStrictMode to false.
Something like this, say your config file is called next.config.mjs:
const nextConfig = {
reactStrictMode: false,
...
};
export default nextConfig; // Or however you export it
